# Is it possible to iterate through a while loop? Or should I try a different approach? Suggestions?

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I have did my fair share of research and can't find much on the topic. Basically, I am trying to replicate a custom turn based battle system. The problem I am facing, is it when the while loop finishes, it just spits out all the results. I would like to see each iteration while the condition has not been met yet.

The loop: javascript

```
const battle = (enemy) => {
    while(xPlayerBattleRound(enemy) != true && enemyBattleRound() != true) {
    }
        if(xPlayer.health <= 0 && enemy.health > 0) {
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
}
```

the functions associated:

```
const selectEnemy = () => {
        enemyNum = Math.round(Math.random())
        enemy = enemies[enemyNum]
        selectedEnemy = enemy
        return selectedEnemy.name
}

xPlayerBattleRound = (enemy) => {
        playerDmg = xPlayerStrike()
        enemy.health = enemy.health - playerDmg
        content += "<br>" + selectAttackStyle() + "" + selectAttackMultiplier() + " towards a " + enemy.name + " and strike it for <span class='bold'>" + playerDmg + " </span>damage."
        document.getElementById('content-creation').innerHTML = content

    if(enemy.health <= 0) {
        content += "<br>You KILLED a " + enemy.name + "! You gained " + enemyExp + " experience."
        document.getElementById('content-creation').innerHTML = content
        enemy.reset()
        return true
    }
}
enemyBattleRound = () => {
    enemyDmg = enemyStrike(enemy)
    xPlayer.health = xPlayer.health - enemyDmg
    content += "<br>A " + enemy.name + " " + selectAttackMultiplier() + " bites you for <span class='bold'>" + enemyDmg + " </span>damage!"
    if(xPlayer.health <= 0) {
        content += "<br>You were MORTALLY wounded by " + enemy.name + "!"
        document.getElementById('content-creation').innerHTML = content
        enemy.reset()
        return true
    }
}
```

Things I have tried, include attempting to setTimeout on the individual functions. I have made several other changes as well. Not sure how to approach this. I also tried different ways as to format it.

Output:

> You punch incompetently towards a wild dog and strike it for 14
> damage. A wild dog competently bites you for 20 damage! You attack
> ordinarily towards a wild dog and strike it for 11 damage. A wild dog
> clumsily bites you for 26 damage! You swing extraordinarily towards a
> wild dog and strike it for 19 damage. A wild dog clumsily bites you
> for 15 damage! You swing incompetently towards a wild dog and strike
> it for 11 damage. A wild dog incompetently bites you for 19 damage!
> You swing incompetently towards a wild dog and strike it for 21
> damage. You KILLED a wild dog! You gained 10 experience.

Rather than the dump, I want to see each line for like 2000ms or something.

Comment: How exactly are you calling `setTimeout`? This should be the way to go.

Comment: @Edric I tried encompassing both the xPlayerBattleRound function as well as the enemyBattleRound and both. The output was broken on either or and the loop becomes infinite when encompassing both

Comment: Could you try enclosing the contents of your _`battle`_ function instead (i.e. `setTimeout` should be inside of the `battle` function but outside of the while loop)?

Comment: you said "I would like to see each iteration while the condition has not been met yet."... why not to try a `do { ... } while(condition)` instead?

Comment: @Edric just the if statement?

Comment: @assembler so I did try this, so unless I am doing something wrong, if I check the condition it fires the function off. Is there a way to do that w/o triggering the function? Or rather, how do I iterate through the while in the do